# React - Logout component issue

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, token, logout

New to react and working on a project of coupons with different client types.
Basically my login component is working fine and I am using `Redux` to control actions.

**AuthComponent:**

```
export class AuthAppState{
    
    public user: NewUserModel = null;
    public constructor(){
        const storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
        if(storedUser) {
            this.user = storedUser;
        }
    }
}

// Step 2 - Define ActionType using enum for all required operations
export enum AuthActionType {
    Register = "Register",
    Login = "Login",
    Logout = "Logout"
}

// Step 3 - Define Action Interface to describe actionAction & payload if needed
export interface AuthAction {
    type: AuthActionType;
    payload?: any; // ? for logout
}

// Step 4 - Export Action Creators functions that gets payload and return relevant Action
export function registerAction(user: UserModel): AuthAction {
    return { type: AuthActionType.Register,payload:user };
}

export function loginAction(user: NewUserModel): AuthAction {
    return { type: AuthActionType.Login ,payload:user};
}

export function logoutAction(): AuthAction {
    return { type: AuthActionType.Logout};
}

// Step 5 - Reducer function perform the required action
export function authReducer(currentState: AuthAppState = new AuthAppState(),
                            action:AuthAction): AuthAppState{
    // const newState = new CatsAppState();
    // newState.cats = currentState.cats;

    const newState = {...currentState} //Spread Operator
    switch(action.type){
        case AuthActionType.Register: //Payload is registered user from backend
            newState.user = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(newState.user)); // Saving in the session storage (won't be deleted)

            break;
        case AuthActionType.Login://Payload is logged i user from backend
            newState.user = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(newState.user)); // Saving in the session storage (won't be deleted)
            break;
        case AuthActionType.Logout: // No payload
            newState.user = null;
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            break;
            
    }
    return newState;
    
}
```

and this is my login component is works just fine.

**LoginComponent:**:

```
function Login(): JSX.Element {

    const history = useHistory();
    const [loginType, setLoginType] = useState("Administrator"); // Save Login Type HERE
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<CredentialsModel>();

    async function send(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
        console.log(credentials);
        let response = null;
        try {

            switch (loginType) {

                case 'Customer':
                    response = await axios.post<NewUserModel>(globals.urls.customer + "login", credentials);
                    store.dispatch(loginAction(response.data));
                    notify.success(SccMsg.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                    break;
                case 'Company':
                    response = await axios.post<NewUserModel>(globals.urls.company + "login", credentials);
                    store.dispatch(loginAction(response.data));
                    notify.success(SccMsg.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                    break;
                case 'Administrator':
                    response = await axios.post<NewUserModel>(globals.urls.admin + "login", credentials);
                    store.dispatch(loginAction(response.data));
                    notify.success(SccMsg.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                    break;
            }
            console.log(response.data);

            history.push(loginType);

        } catch (err) {
            notify.error(err);
        }
    }

    return (

        <div className="base-container " >
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(send)}>
                <div className="header" ></div>
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="image">
                        <img src={loginImage} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder=" email"
                                {...register("email", { required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
                            />
                            {errors.email?.type === 'required' && <span>Enter a valid email address</span>}
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder=" password"
                                {...register("password", {
                                    required: true,
                                    minLength: 4,
                                    maxLength: 12,
                                })}
                            />
                            {errors.password?.type === 'required' && <span>You must enter a password</span>}
                            {errors.password?.type === 'minLength' && <span>Password too short</span>}
                            {errors.password?.type === 'maxLength' && <span>Password too long</span>}

                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="loginas">Login as:</div>
                            <div className="">
                                <select onChange={(e) => setLoginType(e.target.value)} name='clientType' >
                                    <option value="Administrator">ADMINISTRATOR</option>
                                    <option value="Customer">CUSTOMER</option>
                                    <option value="Company">COMPANY</option>

                                </select>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="footer">
                    <Button type="submit" className=".btn" buttonStyle='btn--outline'>Login</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="register">
                    <p >
                        Don't have an account?
                        <br />
                        Please click here to <NavLink to="/Register"> REGISTER</NavLink>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    );
}

export default Login;
```

Once I use right credentials with the right client type user is saved to `LocalStorage` with token from back-end using AuthoMenu Component:

```
interface AuthMenuState {
  user: NewUserModel;
}

class AuthMenu extends Component<{}, AuthMenuState> {
  private unsubscribe: Unsubscribe;
  public constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: store.getState().authState.user,
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    store.subscribe(() => {
      this.setState({ user: store.getState().authState.user });
    });
  }

  public componentWillUnmount(): void {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div className="AuthMenu">
        {this.state.user && (
          <>
            <span>
             Hello {this.state.user.name + " " }
            </span>
            <span> | </span>
            <NavLink to="/logout" className="normal" activeClassName="active">Logout</NavLink>
          </>
        )}

        {!this.state.user && (
          <>
            <span>Hello Guest</span>
            <span> | </span>
            <NavLink to="/login" className="normal" activeClassName="active">Login</NavLink>
            <span> | </span>
            <NavLink to="/register" className="normal" activeClassName="active">Register</NavLink>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

so up until here everything seems to work fine.
I also use react `Hooks` and `Functional Components`.

I am not exactly sure on the right approach on the logout component to remove token.

on my back-end I use jwt as security using intellij.

**Logout Component:**

```
function Logout(): JSX.Element {

    const history = useHistory();

    async function send( ) {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const response = await axios.delete<String>("http://localhost:8080/customer/logout");
        notify.success(SccMsg.LOGOUT_SUCCESS);
        store.dispatch(logoutAction());
        history.push("/home");
    }

useEffect(() => {

  });

    return (
        <></>
       
    );
}
```

My logout controller is very simple.

**BACK-END Controller:**

```
    @DeleteMapping("/logout")
    public  ResponseEntity<?> logout(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token){
        jwtUtils.removeToken(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

}
```

**InterceptorAxios Component:**
const tokenAxios = axios.create();

tokenAxios.interceptors.request.use(request => {

```
    request.headers = {
        "authorization": store.getState().authState.user?.token
    };

    return request;
});
```

export default tokenAxios;

Hope I am clear on my question.
all I need is for the `LocalStorage` to clear once logged out.

**EDIT:**

when using Inspect I get this ERROR:

```
xhr.js:177 DELETE http://localhost:8080/customer/logout 401
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
send @ Logout.tsx:20
(anonymous) @ Logout.tsx:31
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

which I assume has an Authorization problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Notice how in the backend you have mentioned `Authorization` header for token, not `authorization`. For further verification, check the `header` key in your authorization middleware that validates  tokens in your backend.
2. In your `InterceptorAxios`, you need to pass the same `header` key for token with exact punctuation.
3. For JWT tokens, conventionally the tokens have a specific format which is `"Bearer <token>"`

Try this

```
const tokenAxios = axios.create();

tokenAxios.interceptors.request.use(request => {

    request.headers = {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${store.getState().authState.user?.token}`
    };

    return request;
});
export default tokenAxios;
```

Also, ensure that your authorization middleware is working properly.